# cannot connect to database with force encryption

Tags: sql-server, encryption

At server side, I have set the Force Encryption to yes while using SQL Server generated self signed certificate.

At client side, I have set "Encrypt=True; TrustServerCertificate=True;" in my connection string.

However, I am facing this error "the instance of sql server you attempted to connect to requires encryption but this machine does not support it" . By right, my client should be able to connect to sql server with the above setting. Can anyone advise anything that I have missed out?